# DB Manager connection to PostgreSQL failed

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster

I try to load a postgis raster layer. I would like to add the raster by connection with DB Manager an drag and drop into canvas.

> Connection with DB Manager failed with error: UnicodeDecodeError:
>   'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 34: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Connections to other databases are possible. Also it is possible to add shapes.

Comment: What is your server called, are there any special characters in the username or password?

Comment: no special characters, only letters and numbers. What do you mean with "what is your server called?" ip adress, port, user name and pass...this works normally well

Comment: The error suggests a special character. 0xFC could be ü.

Comment: hmmm, definitly no special characters in the database or username or password...strange is that the connection to one database is o.k. and to others are not..can´t see any differences